# sql query only show results based on search criteria

Tags: sql, report

I have a table that has a countless number of entries.  Inside each of these entries (rows), there are multiple columns I am trying to search in (product_1, product_2, product_3 ect).  I am trying to generate a query for a SQL report that spits out the ticket number and products associated with the ticket when it matches the users search criteria.  This is what I have so far (the SELECT statement is only selecting 3 products when the finished product will be selecting 19).

```
SELECT     enteredby, trackingNum, ticketStatus, enteredtime, accountManager, requestor,   shiptoaddress, product_1, product_2, product_3, product_4, product_5, product_6
FROM         c2_ticket
WHERE     (product_1 LIKE '%' + @PRODUCT + '%') OR
                  (product_2 LIKE '%' + @PRODUCT + '%') OR
                  (product_3 LIKE '%' + @PRODUCT + '%') OR
                  (product_4 LIKE '%' + @PRODUCT + '%') OR
                  (product_5 LIKE '%' + @PRODUCT + '%') OR
                  (product_6 LIKE '%' + @PRODUCT + '%') OR
                  (product_7 LIKE '%' + @PRODUCT + '%') OR
                  (product_8 LIKE '%' + @PRODUCT + '%') OR
                  (product_10 LIKE '%' + @PRODUCT + '%') OR
                  (product_11 LIKE '%' + @PRODUCT + '%') OR
                  (product_12 LIKE '%' + @PRODUCT + '%') OR
                  (product_13 LIKE '%' + @PRODUCT + '%') OR
                  (product_14 LIKE '%' + @PRODUCT + '%') OR
                  (product_15 LIKE '%' + @PRODUCT + '%') OR
                  (product_16 LIKE '%' + @PRODUCT + '%') OR
                  (product_17 LIKE '%' + @PRODUCT + '%') OR
                  (product_18 LIKE '%' + @PRODUCT + '%') OR
                  (product_19 LIKE '%' + @PRODUCT + '%')
```

The query spits out the correct information.  However, I only want it to spit out the product based on what the user searches for.  Example, one of these rows might have 6 products listed but only 2 match the search criteria.  Therefore, instead of listing all the products, i only want it to spit out the product matching the search.  I hope I was able to demonstrate what I am trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to have input parameters in your query similar to `@PRODUCT`. You would need to use something like a stored procedure. Then by passing the user search parameter, you could find the records that match the user's search terms.

Example of simple stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ProductSearch
  (
     @userSearchTerm nvarchar(255)
  )
AS
BEGIN
     SELECT *
     FROM c2_ticket
     WHERE product_1 LIKE '%' + @userSearchTerm + '%'
END
```

Did that answer your question?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you correctly.  The query I constructed already searches the DB based on the users search.  However, since there are multiple columns I am searching through and selecting, all the product columns will output, even though only 1 matches the search.  What I am trying to accomplish is, say the user inputs "test".  It searches through columns product_1, product_2, product_3 ect.  if product_1 is the ONLY one that matches the search, then it shouldn't output product_2, product_3, even though I have it selected.

Comment: I would also like to add that I am creating a report in visual studios with this query.  Is there possibly a way to dynamically create a report that only adds columns if the search exists?   example, instead of having product1 product2 product3 fields, it will only add these fields if they match the search